# Spring JPA query findByNameAndType returns null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an interface public interface IAllAccountsRepo extends CrudRepository

and a method in that like below

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM account a where a.id in :id AND a.accountType = :accountType", nativeQuery=true)
    public AccountEntity findByIdAndAccountType(@Param("id") String id, @Param("accountType") String accountType);
```

When i call this method in a helper class, where I will get a list of ids and I loop through them and pass in a filter value to the above method, but i have issues when there is no record matching the query in the database.

It just stops by saying null(when there is no record in db). I do not want to through exception, need to ignore and proceed if i can do that. Is there anyway i can code it to ignore the null and proceed? or do i need criteria query or any other?

`for (String id : accountIdList) {
            accountEntityTemp = iAllAccountsRepo.findByIdAndAccounttype(id, accounttype);
            System.out.println("bs" + accountEntityTemp.getId());
            if (accountEntityTemp != null) {
                accountsEntityList.add(accountEntityTemp);
            }
        }`
accountEntityTemp = null for one id and accounttype and i'm getting the below error.

**2015-12-10 14:20:03.784  WARN 10524 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Handler execution resulted in exception: null**

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uhm... First of all please..

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM account a where a.id =:id AND a.accountType = :accountType", nativeQuery=true)
public AccountEntity findByIdAndAccountType(@Param("id") String id, @Param("accountType") String accountType);
```

That being said...
Just.. why? You're extending crudrepository, so you could as well just write

```
  AccountEntity findByIdAndAccountType(String id, String accountType)
```

IF your attributes on AccountEntity bean are named
Id
AccountType
or change id to Integer, as I don't know its type..

plus man, some care of potential NPE..
you told us it's possible no accountentity is found... yet you do

```
accountEntityTemp = iAllAccountsRepo.findByIdAndAccounttype(id, accounttype);
        System.out.println("bs" + accountEntityTemp.getId());  /// Null pointer here potentially...
        if (accountEntityTemp != null) {
            accountsEntityList.add(accountEntityTemp);
        }
```

at most change it to

```
accountEntityTemp = iAllAccountsRepo.findByIdAndAccounttype(id, accounttype);
        if (accountEntityTemp != null) {
              System.out.println("bs" + accountEntityTemp.getId());
            accountsEntityList.add(accountEntityTemp);
        }
```

Comment: After going through the spring docs i have changed everything but the issue was with print statement which is silly. Thanks much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't even know why you use `IN` function when you are passing a single argument for an id.
Nevertheless, the method you want should look like this:

```
AccountEntity findByIdAndAccountType(Integer id, String accountType);
```